# Why does the stored procedure capture IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool as the user instead of current user ID?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have an asp.net c# web forms application running on SqlServer 2012.  When I insert data into the database I capture the ID of the current user.  I use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` to get the ID.  It works if the sql Insert Into statement is in the code behind.  But it captures  'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' as the current user if I use a stored procedure.  How can I get the stored procedure to capture the current user ID instead of the DefaulAppPool?

Comment: That's the user account the app pool is using. Are you trying to capture the actual user i.e. the person using the browser ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to capture the id of the person using the browser.  I just moved the sql from the stored procedure to the code behind and it works just fine - it captures the user's ID.  However, I would prefer to get it to work from the stored procedure if it's possible.

Comment: Is your site using Windows Authentication ? If so then `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` should return the current Windows user. If it's a public facing site using anonymous or forms authentication, you'll need to implement some sort of membership mechanism.